# json-glib: undefined reference to 'json_parser_new' collect2 error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: json, gcc

I am getting started with json-glib and I followed this parser example: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/JsonGlib. The installation was successful and make check showed all the tests were passed. However, I couldn't figure out what I missed to get it run. I used the command:

```
gcc json-parser.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` \
  -Ijson-glib-1.2.8 -o json-parser
```

and got the following load errors:

```
json-parser.o: In function `main':
json-parser.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `json_parser_new'
json-parser.c:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `json_parser_load_from_file'
json-parser.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `g_print'
json-parser.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `g_error_free'
json-parser.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
json-parser.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `json_parser_get_root'
json-parser.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the symbol table of the object file and these functions were undefined. What did I miss?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to link against the library you are trying to use. This involves adding it to your linker arguments. If it's already installed on your system, you may want to try something like `\`pkg-config --cflags json-glib-1.2.8\``. Same thing about `gobject-2.0`. Otherwise you need to figure out what `-l` and `-L` arguments to use.

Comment: Thanks! json-glib is indeed in pkgconfig. Adding it solves the problem.